# index(of: Int) method of Range in swift return incorrect value

Tags: swift, indexing, range

When using index(of: Int) method on a half open range object, it always returns an incorrect value if the range does not start at 0. See the code below.

```
let range = (3 ..< 10)
let indexOfRange = range.index(of: 5) // return 5


let array = Array(5 ..< 10)
let indexOfArray = array.index(of: 5)  // returns 0
```

I don't understand why such result is produced. Can anyone please explain?

Comment: [`Bound`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/rangeexpression/2894257-bound) vs [`Int`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int), if you don't use type-inference, you could see you are dealing with two different types.

Comment: @holex actually they are both `Int` in Swift 4.1

Comment: @Sulthan, I cannot check it but that seems a more reasonable type for it, despite it is still not a traditional _index_ (like in the case of array).

Comment: It doesn't produce an incorrect value. It produces a correct value that you didn't expect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indices are opaque objects. If it's not an array, you shouldn't assume they are zero-based or even that they are integers (for an example see `String.Index`). To get a zero-based integer index, you need to get the distance from the `startIndex`:

```
let range = (3 ..< 10)
let opaqueIndex = range.index(of: 5)
let integerIndex = range.distance(from: range.startIndex, to: opaqueIndex!)
print(integerIndex) // 2
```

However, for `Int` ranges that's basically the same as:

```
let integerIndex = 5 - range.lowerOffset
```

The interesting part is that it seems ranges cannot be subscripted (ambiguous definition), therefore there is probably no point to get the index in the first place.

Comment: Funnily enough, until recently (but still in 4.1) the standard library actually intentionally defined ambiguous overloads for `Range`’s `subscript` in order to prevent people from falling into the zero-indexing-assumption trap and saying things like `let r = 5 ..< 10; let i = r[0]`. You’ll be able to do so in 4.2 though.

Comment: (the intentionally ambiguous overloads were removed in [this patch](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/13342/files#diff-f16468aeb2a58bd1e596886ab43c1a0cL280) for those interested :) )